# React 18 Dependencies array and functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs

есть например `useEffect`, и если у меня есть какая-то *колбек функция* для него, я пишу ~валидный код, а потом вижу варнинг:

- React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'onSuccess' **...**

Вопрос в чем, зачем создан такой варнинг, если это функция извне, и мне например нужен эффект по запуску, т.е. `[]`, или нужен по изменению 1 пелеменной - `[oneSingleVar]`; по итогу - мне просто привыкать их игнорировать?

Или зачем колбек функцию указывать, если она ~не_меняется?

---

Code example:

```js
const ModuleAuth = ({onSuccess, isProd = true, token})=>{
    const checkAuth = useCallback(()=>{
        const tokenNew = isProd ? getCookie('authorization_token') : token;
        return tokenNew ? onSuccess({isAuthorized: true, token: tokenNew}) : redirectToLoginPage();
    }, [isProd, token, onSuccess]);

    useEffect(checkAuth, [checkAuth]);

    return <></>;
};

export default ModuleAuth;
```

Как здесь выставлять депсы?

Comment: Во всех хуках должны быть правильно объявлены зависимости. Если у вас не меняется параметр компонента, т.е. onSuccess, то у вас useEffect сработает 1 раз при инициализации

Comment: @AlexanderKiselev а если мне так и нужно, но варнинг пишет(требует) указать зависимость к функции - зачем?